# Matplotlib time series historical vs prediction plot shifting one month in the x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, data-science, data-visualization

I'm trying to plot historical and predicted data into a single line in a single plot. The data ranges from **'2020-01-01'** **'2021-12-31'**. When the plot is produced, it plots the data from one month shifted to right in the x-axis. My code is given as follows.

```
import pandas as pd

index = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2021-12-31', freq='M')
series = pd.DataFrame({'num':np.random.randint(0, 50, size=(len(index)))}, index=index)

def plot_series(series):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.dates as mdates
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 6))
    ax = plt.axes()
    plt.plot(series.index, series.num.values, color='black', label='Historical')
    plt.plot(series.index[18:], series.num.values[18:], color='red', label='Forecasted')
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 105, 5))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.title("Time Series Plot: Historial to Forecasted")
    plt.xlabel("Month")
    plt.ylabel("Score");
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate(rotation=80)
    plt.show();
    return fig
```

Here is the resulting plot.
[image]

Why this behavior is happening and how can fix it?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I expect the line to be start from '2020-01-01' and end at '2021-12-01'.

Comment: So the question is how to adjust the x-axis range?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney yes..you got it right.

Answer (score 2):

- See the inline comments

  - `ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[1:-1])`: set the x-ticks to remove the undesired ticks at the beginning and end of the axis.
  - `ax.margins(0.015, tight=True)`: or set the margins to be small and tight
- The code was adjusted to only use the object oriented approach, `axes`.
- Don't include imports inside the function, they should all be at the top of the script.
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

index = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2021-12-31', freq='M')
np.random.seed(365)  # makes the sample data the same each time
series = pd.DataFrame({'num':np.random.randint(0, 50, size=(len(index)))}, index=index)

def plot_series(series):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 6))
    ax.plot(series.index, series.num.values, color='black', label='Historical')
    ax.plot(series.index[18:], series.num.values[18:], color='red', label='Forecasted')
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 105, 5))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
    
#     ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[1:-1])  # set the x-ticks to remove the first and list value

    ax.legend(loc='best')
    ax.set(title='Time Series Plot: Historial to Forecasted', xlabel='Month', ylabel='Score')
    
    ax.margins(0.015, tight=True)  # or set the margins to be small and tight
    
    fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=80)
    fig.tight_layout()


plot_series(series)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect/print the `index` object that you generate, you'll see that the dates are at month's end.  The [docs for the times series offset alias](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases) (which is the `freq` argument passed to `pd.date_range()` ) specify the available offset aliases.

You actually want `freq='MS'` for the month-start frequency.  Changing the definition of `index` to:

```
index = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2021-12-31', freq='MS')
```

gives the following output:

[image: month_start_image]

Answer (score 0):

One way I found to fix the x-axis is to use the `shift()` function. I shifted the index to one step left: `series.index.shift(-1)`

Here is the final function:

```
def plot_series(series):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.dates as mdates
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 6))
    ax = plt.axes()
    plt.plot(series.index.shift(-1), series.num.values, color='black', label='Historical')
    plt.plot(series.index.shift(-1)[18:], series.num.values[18:], color='red', label='Forecasted')
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 105, 5))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.title("Time Series Plot: Historial to Forecasted")
    plt.xlabel("Month")
    plt.ylabel("Score");
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate(rotation=80)
    plt.show();
    return fig
```